# How to set configuration in Hive-Site.xml file for hive metastore connection?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, impala, metastore

I want to connect MetaStore using the java code. I have no idea how to set configuration setting in Hive-Site.xml file and where I'll post the Hive-Site.xml file. Please help.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.ConfVars;

public class HiveMetastoreJDBCTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            HiveConf conf = new HiveConf();
            conf.addResource(new Path("file:///path/to/hive-site.xml"));
            Class.forName(conf.getVar(ConfVars.METASTORE_CONNECTION_DRIVER));
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    conf.getVar(ConfVars.METASTORECONNECTURLKEY),
                    conf.getVar(ConfVars.METASTORE_CONNECTION_USER_NAME),
                    conf.getVar(ConfVars.METASTOREPWD));

            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(
                "select t.tbl_name, s.location from tbls t " +
                "join sds s on t.sd_id = s.sd_id");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " : " + rs.getString(2));
            }
        }        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines in your **hive-site.xml**:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hiveuser</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>hivepass</value>
</property>
```

In `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive`, `3306` is your default mysql port; `hive` is our mysql database name for hive metastore.
Change `hiveuser` to your mysql hive username and `hivepass` to your mysql hive password.

Do this step in terminal, if you haven't created a database for hive metastore in mysql:

`mysql -u root -p`

Enter your mysql root password.

`mysql> create database hive;`

`mysql> create user 'hiveuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'hivepass';`

`mysql> GRANT all on *.* to 'hiveuser'@localhost identified by 'hivepass';`

`mysql>  flush privileges;`

Here, `hiveuser` and `hivepass` are whatever username and password you give for hive metastore respectively.

> NOTE: You need to have **mysql-jdbc-connector.jar** in **$HIVE_HOME/lib** and
>   **$HADOOP_HOME/lib**

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Hive-site.xml here is sample from my testing machine. This is for setting up hive metastore with MySql server installed on localhost.

```
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
 <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
 <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
</property>
<property>
 <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
 <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
 <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
</property>
<property>
 <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
 <value>hive</value>
 <description>user name for connecting to mysql server </description>
</property>
<property>
 <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
 <value>123456</value>
 <description>password for connecting to mysql server </description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

This file you need to place inside `<system_path>/apache-hive-x.xx.x-bin/conf` directory

I do not have much idea about how to use this file in java. But by specifying connection string in java code you can do it as below

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class WriteToHive {
    private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
    static Connection con;
    static Statement stmt;

    public WriteToHive() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, Exception {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("No JDBC Hive Driver found");
            //System.exit(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e);
            //System.exit(1);
        }

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/rajen","","");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/rajen","","");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        //Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://","","");
        String tableName = "company_mas_hive_eclipse_trial";

        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("use rajen");

        String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rajen.company_mas_hive_eclipse_trial (" +
              "Name string," + 
              "dateofincorporation string," + 
              "country string)" +
              "ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY \",\"";
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'";
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        if (res.next()){
            System.out.println(res.getString(1));
        }

        sql = "describe " + tableName;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println("=========================================");
        while (res.next()) {
          System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
        }
        System.out.println("=========================================");

        // load data into table
        // NOTE: filepath has to be local to the hive server
        // NOTE: /tmp/a.txt is a ctrl-A separated file with two fields per line
        String filepath = "/home/seo/Refrence_Doc/sampledata/companymas"; //"/rajen/companymas";
        sql = "load data local inpath '" + filepath + "' into table " + tableName;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        // load data into table
        // NOTE: filepath has to be local to the hive server
        // NOTE: /tmp/a.txt is a ctrl-A separated file with two fields per line
        filepath = "/rajen/companymas";
        sql = "load data inpath '" + filepath + "' into table " + tableName;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        //res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        // select * query
        sql = "select * from " + tableName;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getString(1)) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
        }

        // regular hive query
        sql = "select count(*) from " + tableName;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println(res.getString(1));
        }
    }

    public void createTable(String def, String dbname) throws SQLException{
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("use " + dbname);
        stmt.executeQuery(def);
    }

    public static void loadData(String filepath, String tableName) throws SQLException{
        stmt.executeQuery("load data local inpath '" + filepath + "' into table " + tableName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for valuable reply. But I am trying to connect Hive-Metastore using the java code not MySql. If you have the code please give me.